# How to check if AWS ECR image exists by URI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

How can I check if an image exists in ECR using AWS CLI given its URI like:

`xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai-api:2022-08-25T23-10-58-main`

?

I've tried `describe-images` with parameters `--image-ids`, but it can only accept `--image-ids imageDigest=string,imageTag=string ...`, no `URI` option.

Do you have a script that can check if ECR image exists by URI?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use `AWS CLI` is a wrong way.

We should use `docker manifest inspect` to check whether the image exists.